# parse_dates keyword of read_excel is not implemented

Tags: date, parsing

I am getting the following error when i read excel file: "NotImplementedError: parse_dates keyword of read_excel is not implemented". I don't get this error with read_csv

```
import pandas as p
calendar = p.read_excel('../data/testdates.xlsx', parse_dates=['date'])
```

I am using 
python: 3.6.0.final.0
pandas: 0.19.2

I don't get this error with pandas 0.20.3 Can someone point a way out?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed issue. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/12051
Updated to 0.22 and the problem disapeared.